# SP2013 on-premise, cannot change mysite's theme with Design gallery

Tags: theme

We are using SharePoint 2013 On-premise. User want to change the theme of their "My site" or their "blog". In the browser he type in the URL like this:

```
http://mysite.domain.com/personal/testuser//_layouts/15/designgallery.aspx
```

It go to Design Gallery. After he pick a theme and click "try it out", page show up with

> "403 FORBIDDEN" error.

Is it our configuration settings problem or are SharePoint users are not allowed  to change blog's theme?

Answer (score 0):

my own has this url
https://portal.XXXXXXXXXX.com/my/YYYYYYYYYY/Blog/default.aspx

I do not have the double slash //

Have you tried turning on publishing features on the main personal site?

Comment: I have tried with single slash but still the same.